# How to test for a player's height

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a mining turtle-like one command contraption and I need to execute on the turtle when it gets to `y=16`.

This is the command I use:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[y=16,dy=0,tag=Bot] remove MiningDown
```

for some reason it does not work. How do I make it work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters will default to the sender's coordinates (such as the command block's XYZ position) if not defined. Your command will run at the command block's X and Z but with Y set to 16.

To overcome this, you can use `/execute` to change the origin to that of your intended target, so that XYZ are filled in with their coordinates. The nested command will modify the Y value (or you could use `/execute`'s Y coordinate:

```
/execute @e[tag=Bot] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players tag @e[y=16,dy=0,c=1] remove MiningDown
```

Or:

```
/execute @e[tag=Bot] ~ 16 ~ /scoreboard players tag @e[dy=0,c=1] remove MiningDown
```

Comment: Thanks it worked that is very nice to know! also are you the some awesome person from planet minecraft?